# peerinvalid Peer yo@1.0.0-rc.1 wants bower @ ~ 0.9.2

Tags: yeoman

When installing the "npm install-g yo grunt-cli bower", I get an error
"npm ERR! peerinvalid The package bower does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer yo@1.0.0-rc.1 wants bower @ ~ 0.9.2"
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 16):

The solution to this problem:

https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/48

## npm update -g yo

Comment: You are bang on the target, it just resolved my npm conflict as well, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I came here from a google search. the solution on this page did not work. instead I had to update bower with just:

```
npm update -g bower
```

and then re-run the install for yeoman. For some reason npm update -g yo does not update bower you must do that separately.